# "ImportError" related to the "AbstractUser" class in the "django.contrib.auth.models" module

Tags: django-models, import, circular-dependency, abstractuser

I hope you're doing well. I am currently facing an issue with a circular import in my Django project's models.py file. The specific error message is related to importing AbstractUser from django.contrib.auth.models. I have been trying to resolve this issue, and after some research, I came across a proposed solution that involves modifying the models.py file.

Here's the solution:

Import get_user_model at the beginning of your models.py file:

python

```
   from django.contrib.auth import get_user_modelReplace the direct import of User
```

```
   from django.contrib.auth.models with get_user_model():
```

python

```
    User = get_user_model()Remove the import statement for AbstractUser since it's not directly used in the file:
```

python

## Remove this line:

```
    from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser, BaseUserManager, PermissionsMixin
```

After making these changes, the modified models.py file should look something like this:

python

```
from django.db import models                                                                                                                              from django.db.models.signals import post_save                                                                                                   from django.dispatch import receiver                                                               from django.utils import timezone                                                                  from django.conf import settings                                                                                                                                            from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model                                                            from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim
```

```
User = get_user_model()  # Use get_user_model() to get the User model
```

## ... rest of the code ...

I have followed these steps, but unfortunately, the issue persists. I would greatly appreciate any insights, suggestions, or alternative solutions that the community might have. If there's additional information needed to understand the problem better, please let me know.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Best regards,
Bodmax